# What model to use? Heckman-Two-Stage? Tobit? OLS?

Tags: least-squares, methodology, tobit-regression, method-comparison, heckman

I am currently researching innovation with firm level data. I have a nice dataset, which allows to analyze the variable

`inno`

which is

`revenue generated with new products in relation to total revenue of the firm.`

Among others, I am trying to explain `inno` with `R&D-Intensity`, that is the amount of research and development expences (also scaled by the turnover of the respective firm). Here is a scatter plot of `inno` and `R&D`:

[image: Scatter inno and R&D]
As you can see from the scatter, I am also differentiation between two types of firms (start ups "+" and established firms "o"). I discussed my idea in several small workshops and the number of suggested models is vast.

Most commonly I was suggested to use a Tobit model. The distribution of the endogenous variable is bounded from below (0%) and above (100%) by definition. But does that necessarily constitute a censorship? I was also advised a Heckman-Two-Stage model, but I don't really see why. Lastly, OLS was advised.

So my questions are the following:

1. What model do you suggest and why?
2. And, do you think a Tobit Model is appropiate?

Comment: A tobit model would probably be worth trying at least, possibly with R&D intensity in (continuity-corrected) logs or something like that. A two-stage model may well be worth trying, especially to account for the possiblity of different effects at the zero-hurdle (whether or not to use new products at all) and the rest of the distribution. Finally, beta regression might be worth trying if the cases that are exactly zero or non-zero can be reasonably dealt with (either by adding a small correction or using a two-stage model again).

Comment: Thanks, but is the data really censored from aboth and/or below? I don't see why that would be the case?

Comment: The censoring is a "trick" that often/sometimes happens to fit the data well enough. The story is: There is a latent propensity to innovate, say inno*, that cannot be observed directly. The variable you can observe is inno, the fraction of revenue generated by new products. If the propensity inno* becomes negative, then no revenue comes from new products (inno = 0). If the propensity inno* is larger than 100, you observe inno = 100. And if you then assume that the latent propensity is inno* = a + b * r&d + error you obtain a censored model. See textbooks on the tobit model for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, the "trick" is clear to me and it makes sense. But the data is still not censored in the classical sense. I now estimated TObit and OLS and both yield similar results (i.e. sign and significancy of the coefficients).

Comment: That depends on what you call “classical“. Many would argue that Tobin's model is very classical. It' just that the concepts of partially observed latent variables and censored survival times are different even if they can be tackled with related statistcal methods.

Comment: Thinking out loud here: regarding tricks, if we interpret the `inno` variable as the probability of an innovation being successful you could also try a logit model, just to see what comes out. Nevertheless, the response as chosen here doesn't seem fit to model the success of an innovation, since a very successful innovation of a huge company could still only show here as a very low percentage, due to the amount of total revenue generated. Thus I'd argue an index independent of the firm size (revenue and product range) would make much more sense, e.g. only the nominator of `inno`.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand, and I'm paraphrasing [Maddala](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=isbn%3A9780470015124) here, that the tobit model is meant for situations in which **the latent variable** (of which we only have censored observations) **can in principle take on any value on the real line**. This doesn't seem to be the case with your `inno` variable. Instead, you observe zero values for this variable because of decisions of individuals. So the appropriate procedure would be to model the decisions that produce the zero observations, rather than using the tobit model.